# Как подключить файл с сервера в плеер?

Tags: javascript

Как запустить этот `http://jplayer.org/audio/m4a/Miaow-07-Bubble.m4a`, а не с компьютера?

Что здесь лишнее и куда писать url, чтобы файл загружался после загрузки страницы и работал `canvas`?

```js
window.onload = function() {
  
  var file = document.getElementById("thefile");
  var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
  
  file.onchange = function() {
    var files = this.files;
    audio.src = URL.createObjectURL(files[0]);
    audio.load();
    audio.play();
    var context = new AudioContext();
    var src = context.createMediaElementSource(audio);
    var analyser = context.createAnalyser();

    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    src.connect(analyser);
    analyser.connect(context.destination);

    analyser.fftSize = 256;

    var bufferLength = analyser.frequencyBinCount;
    console.log(bufferLength);

    var dataArray = new Uint8Array(bufferLength);

    var WIDTH = canvas.width;
    var HEIGHT = canvas.height;

    var barWidth = (WIDTH / bufferLength) * 2.5;
    var barHeight;
    var x = 0;

    function renderFrame() {
      requestAnimationFrame(renderFrame);

      x = 0;

      analyser.getByteFrequencyData(dataArray);

      ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
      ctx.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

      for (var i = 0; i < bufferLength; i++) {
        barHeight = dataArray[i];
        
        var r = barHeight + (25 * (i/bufferLength));
        var g = 250 * (i/bufferLength);
        var b = 50;

        ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + ")";
        ctx.fillRect(x, HEIGHT - barHeight, barWidth, barHeight);

        x += barWidth + 1;
      }
    }

    audio.play();
    renderFrame();
  };
};
```

```css
#thefile {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  z-index: 100;
}

#canvas {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

audio {
  position: fixed;
  left: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <input type="file" id="thefile" accept="audio/*" />
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
  <audio id="audio" controls></audio>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

url писать в тег аудио в качестве src:

```html
<div id="content">
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    <audio id="audio" src = "http://jplayer.org/audio/m4a/Miaow-07-Bubble.m4a" crossorigin="anonymous" controls></audio>
</div>
<script>
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");  
var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
var context = new AudioContext();
var src = context.createMediaElementSource(audio);
var analyser = context.createAnalyser();
src.connect(analyser);
analyser.connect(context.destination);
analyser.fftSize = 256;
var bufferLength = analyser.frequencyBinCount;
console.log(bufferLength);
var dataArray = new Uint8Array(bufferLength);
var WIDTH = canvas.width;
var HEIGHT = canvas.height;
var barWidth = (WIDTH / bufferLength) * 2.5;
var barHeight;
var x = 0;
audio.onplay = function() {
    function renderFrame() {
        requestAnimationFrame(renderFrame);
        x = 0;
        analyser.getByteFrequencyData(dataArray);
        ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        for (var i = 0; i < bufferLength; i ++) {
            barHeight = dataArray[i];
            var r = barHeight + (25 * (i / bufferLength));
            var g = 250 * (i / bufferLength);
            var b = 50;
            ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + ")";
            ctx.fillRect(x, HEIGHT - barHeight, barWidth, barHeight);
            x += barWidth + 1;
        }
    }
    renderFrame();
};
</script>
```

Запускаем анализатор нажатием на play в панели плеера.

Comment: Пример не работает

Comment: Какая ошибка в консоли?

Comment: Нажми на выполнить код, анализатор не работает

Comment: На этой странице с вопросом может работать, может нет, это ни о чём не говорит. Желательно скопировать код на компьютер или сервер. Там и ошибку можно увидеть.

Comment: [живая ссылка](http://tolmatux.strana.de/pleer.htm) На компе и ноуте работает, на андроиде нет. Почему - не знаю, обычно на андроиде работает всё, что и на компе.

Comment: Не знаю, на ноуте не работает, телефоне тоже, ошибок нет

Comment: Ещё странно, иногда автоматически запускается воспроизведение, а не запускается даже от кнопки. И ещё не понятно как его привязать к `jplayer` там `id` постоянно меняется `jp_audio_?`

Comment: Тогда мне придётся изучать jplayer

Comment: В общем, суть привязки - должен паралелльно быть невидимый элемент аудио с таким же подключенным аудиофайлом, и к нему подключить анализатор. Или использовать плагин wavesurfer.js с визуализацией.

Comment: Wavesurfer я уже использую. А визуализацию не получилось подключить

Comment: Я уже подключил.

Answer (score 0):

В этом коде реализация привязки визуализатора к jplayer-у:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<!-- Website Design By: www.happyworm.com -->
<title>Demo : jPlayer as an audio player</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<link href="../../dist/skin/blue.monday/css/jplayer.blue.monday.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../dist/jplayer/jquery.jplayer.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
        ready: function (event) {
            $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                title: "Bubble",
                m4a: "http://jplayer.org/audio/m4a/Miaow-07-Bubble.m4a",
                oga: "http://jplayer.org/audio/ogg/Miaow-07-Bubble.ogg"
            });
        },
        swfPath: "../../dist/jplayer",
        supplied: "m4a, oga",
        wmode: "window",
        useStateClassSkin: true,
        autoBlur: false,
        smoothPlayBar: true,
        keyEnabled: true,
        remainingDuration: true,
        toggleDuration: true
    });
});
//]]>
</script>
<style>
#thefile {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  z-index: 100;
}

#canvas {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: blue;
}

audio {
  position: fixed;
  left: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    <audio id="audio" src = "http://jplayer.org/audio/m4a/Miaow-07-Bubble.m4a" crossorigin="anonymous"></audio>
</div>
<div id="jquery_jplayer_1" class="jp-jplayer"></div>
<div id="jp_container_1" class="jp-audio" role="application" aria-label="media player">
    <div class="jp-type-single">
        <div class="jp-gui jp-interface">
            <div class="jp-controls">
                <button class="jp-play" role="button" tabindex="0" onclick="visualize()">play</button>
                <button class="jp-stop" role="button" tabindex="0" onclick="audio.pause()">stop</button>
            </div>
            <div class="jp-progress">
                <div class="jp-seek-bar">
                    <div class="jp-play-bar"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="jp-volume-controls">
                <button class="jp-mute" role="button" tabindex="0">mute</button>
                <button class="jp-volume-max" role="button" tabindex="0">max volume</button>
                <div class="jp-volume-bar">
                    <div class="jp-volume-bar-value"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="jp-time-holder">
                <div class="jp-current-time" role="timer" aria-label="time">&nbsp;</div>
                <div class="jp-duration" role="timer" aria-label="duration">&nbsp;</div>
                <div class="jp-toggles">
                    <button class="jp-repeat" role="button" tabindex="0">repeat</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="jp-details">
            <div class="jp-title" aria-label="title">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
        <div class="jp-no-solution">
            <span>Update Required</span>
            To play the media you will need to either update your browser to a recent version or update your <a href="http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/" target="_blank">Flash plugin</a>.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");  
var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
var context = new AudioContext();
var src = context.createMediaElementSource(audio);
var analyser = context.createAnalyser();
src.connect(analyser);
analyser.fftSize = 256;
var bufferLength = analyser.frequencyBinCount;
console.log(bufferLength);
var dataArray = new Uint8Array(bufferLength);
var WIDTH = canvas.width;
var HEIGHT = canvas.height;
var barWidth = (WIDTH / bufferLength) * 2.5;
var barHeight;
var x = 0;
function visualize() {
    if(audio.paused){audio.play()}else{audio.pause()};
    function renderFrame() {
        requestAnimationFrame(renderFrame);
        x = 0;
        analyser.getByteFrequencyData(dataArray);
        ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        for (var i = 0; i < bufferLength; i ++) {
            barHeight = dataArray[i];
            var r = barHeight + (25 * (i / bufferLength));
            var g = 250 * (i / bufferLength);
            var b = 50;
            ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + ")";
            ctx.fillRect(x, HEIGHT - barHeight, barWidth, barHeight);
            x += barWidth + 1;
        }
    }
    renderFrame();
};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

И на всякий случай [живая ссылка](http://tolmatux.strana.de/jplayer/examples/blue.monday/demo-01.html)

Сам jplayer я скачивал [тут](https://github.com/jplayer/jPlayer/releases/tag/2.9.2)

Comment: Это не привязка, плеер и спектр работают по отдельности, пауза не работает. Тега audio в html разметке не должно быть, этот тег генерируется плеером. Вот пример плеера https://codepen.io/stopani/pen/rNyxvzJ

Comment: Но тогда придётся разбирать, как фунциклирует весь wavesurfer. Представьте, сколько труда ... Паузу я исправил.

Comment: К тому же после всего прямую ссылку в и-нет на подключение этого плагина уже не использовать, т. к., он не возвращает данных для построения спектрограммы. Нужно его скачать, переделать, а может у него есть лицензия, запрещающая менять код. В общем, ещё есть вариант без плагинов сделать одновременно оба графика - waveform и analise.